# Microsoft Excel vlookup formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have two sheets as below.

Sheet1:

```
Sno  Emp ID   Name   Address
1    101      X.     ?
2    01       Y.     ?
```

Sheet2:

```
Sno   Emp ID  Name    Address
1     10      D.      XX
2     101     X.      YY
```

I need that address in Sheet2 in Sheet1 address column.

Please help me out.

Comment: I assume that `Sno` doesn't matter but `Emp ID` and `Name` need to match... If I am correct, then [THIS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214142) should be what you are looking for...

Comment: So... yeah.... glad to be of assistance. If it worked out, please let the community know. Accept by check-marking the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want the Home Address of the Employee**:
Use the:

 **VLOOKUP(** lookup ref, table ref search, result col, match **)** 

= vlookup(B2, table-sheet2, 2nd column, exact match) 

= vlookup(employee ID 101, table on sheet2, Name, exact match)

**C2**: Name Search, referencing the Employee ID, to TABLE

=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$D$5,2,FALSE), for Name Search ref, Emp.ID

**D2**: Address Search, referenceing the Employee ID, to TABLE

=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$D$5,3,FALSE)

**Note**: It's necessary to use the **static notation $B$2:$D$5** for copy/paste functionality so that you can paste the formula to the cells in the column; else if you use dynamic notation B2:D5, the next cell will search B3:D6, then B4:D7, and so on, and that's unintended. The **TABLE** must be in, it is assumed by EXCEL, **alphabetical/numeric order**!

---

[image]

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` formula is incorrect. What happens if `Sheet1!B3` is 10? `Sheet1!D3` should be "40 Uncle Ave." The question wasn't clear about which cells were to be matched, but assuming `Emp ID`, the correct formula for your answer is `=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$D$5,3,FALSE)`. `VLOOKUP`'s 4th argument is not  "lookup val col"; it's range_lookup, a logical value: to find the closest match in the first column (sorted in ascending order) = TRUE or omitted; find an exact match = FALSE. Please fix your answer.

Comment: It's not working pls just let me know the exact formula

Comment: @Arun Sorry for that. Thanks to Creidhne that pointed it out. I hastily put the wrong table reference from a context of the "cell address" problem. It should be okay now. Answer adjusted.

Comment: @creidhne Nice catch. I looked at it and sort of remembered that I changed it but then forgot to update the references. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun Thought you disappeared forever. Let me know if it worked out and check the box as answered if it does. Good luck in future EXCEL use!

Comment: Wow... That worked guys... Thank you so much u made my day really .... :). I was trying it so delay in responding and whr do I Mark it as answered ?

Comment: @Arun Glad to have helped. Please check the check-mark on the page to accept the answer. Look forward to your expertise in the future!

Comment: Done I did thanq once again ...... :)

Comment: @Arun You got it! When you are a pro you'll come back and help out the new noobies :)